# How do you enable the CM4IO boards RTC (Real time clock) in Ubuntu 20.10 server (5.8.0-1013-raspi)

Tags: server, raspberrypi, 20.10, arm64

How do you enable the CM4IO boards RTC (Real time clock) in Ubuntu 20.10 server (5.8.0-1013-raspi)

Answer (score 1):

[Page 6 of the data sheet for this board](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.org/cm4io/cm4io-datasheet.pdf) has this handy tidbit:

> To enable the I2C bus to the RTC you will need `dtparam=i2c_vc=on` set in `config.txt`. The RTC then will be on `i2c-10` address `0x51` (7bit address)

The `config.txt` file they're referring to can be found in `/boot/firmware`.

Hope this gives you what you need

Comment: Thanks for that.   doesn't make any difference to the Ubuntu boot.. and no i2c detected.. I'm assuming that Ubuntu doesn't yet support it.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting with the early release of Hirsute Gorilla and it works with the CM4 real time clock.

So my conclusion is that the 20.10 kernel/modules do not fully support the Compute Module 4 and that this feature appears to be working in 21.04.